# Accordion style FAQ with two levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I am using Squarespace to build my website, as I am a coding newb. I found some code online to implement an accordion style FAQ that I am trying to build. I have this code injected in the page header. Then I put the FAQ content in a markdown block and used the markdown notation ### for h3 headings and #### for h4 headings. As such I have two types of headings in my markdown FAQ, which are then targeted in the javascript code to collapse by default and expand to show the accompanying paragraph when clicked.

I first only used the h4 headings and the code below. This works smooth as you can see on [this](https://www.nielsgoossens.be/blog/tatbijles) webpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content h4').css('cursor','pointer');
    $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h4").nextUntil("h4").slideToggle();
    $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h4").click(function() {$(this).nextUntil("h4").slideToggle();});
    });
    </script>
```

On another page I need two levels to collapse by default however. So I figured I just added the same code, but replacing h4 by h3. This gives the code below. Unfortunately this doesn't work as you can see on [this](https://www.nielsgoossens.be/blog/toelatingsexamen-artsamptandarts-praktische-info) page (item +2.). All text is visible by default and the h4 headings (+2.1, +2.2,...) disappear. When I click the h3 (+2...), the h4 headings suddenly appear.

I only want to show the h3 headings by default. When someone clicks on it, the paragraph below it should show if there are no h4 headings. If there are h4 headings, these headings should show collapsed first and only when someone clicks on them, the accompanying paragraph should show. So I want two levels of headings that can be fully collapsed and fully expanded by clicking on them.

What should I change in the code below to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content h4').css('cursor','pointer');
        $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h4").nextUntil("h4").slideToggle();
        $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h4").click(function() {$(this).nextUntil("h4").slideToggle();});
        });
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3').css('cursor','pointer');
        $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3").nextUntil("h3").slideToggle();
        $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h3").click(function() {$(this).nextUntil("h3").slideToggle();});
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Don't add jQuery more than once (and we don't need to see that anyway), and your various statements can all be in a single `document.ready` block.

Comment: Also, we need to see a sample of your HTML here. It's not considered adequate to link to another site for that.

Comment: Please do include all relevant code in a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. In this case, an example of the HTML is needed in order to reproduce the issue. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable code example.